# Caja plugin for EXIF metadata?

Tags: mate, caja, exif

Do you know a Caja plugin that showing file's EXIF metadata in properties window ?

In Nautilus there is a tab "Audio" or "Image" where metadata are displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Caja's source code - it has [EXIF-related functionality](https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja/blob/ef29013fdfd0df5d4a3cc6c5a8fb1583aabef952/src/caja-image-properties-page.c#L32) in all current versions.

So you need to have exif-packages installed in the system. Caja depends on [`libexif12` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/caja).
If unsure install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libexif12
```

And then you check the information in *Image* tab of file *Properties*.
It will show at least image type and dimensions.
If image has EXIF information - then it will be displayed too:

> [image: Caja, Properties → Image]

If you do not have EXIF in this tab - then it means that it was removed from image.
You can use `exiftool` from `libimage-exiftool-perl` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fexiftool) to confirm.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It works for image files, but not for audio files (mp3, flac, ...)